# Dynamic SQL Query and output in simple GWT

Tags: java, sql, gwt

I have the below table(company_details) in oracle 10g.

```
STATE       COMPANY_NAME        AVG_SAL
 KN             GOO               $5500
 IN             SCOPE             $6000
 AR             FB                $8250
 CL             PAL               $4500
 CL             GOO               $6000
 AR             GOO               $7000
 IN             FB                $3999
```

I would like form an output shown below and display it in simple GWT datagrid.

```
STATE  count(goo)  AVG_SAL  count(SCOPE)  AVG_SAL  count(FB) AVG_SAL count(PAL)  AVG_SAL
KN        1          5500        --            --          --     --        --         --
IN       --           --          1           6000        1        3999     --         --
AR        1          7000         --            --         1       8250      --        --
CL        1          6000        --             --       --          --       1      4500
```

I tried writing the below query but it didn't work. Kindly help

```
select
    state,
    count(*)as "GOO_Records", to_char(SUM(average_sal),'$999,999') as "GOO_AVGSAL"
    from company_details 
where company_status = 'OPEN' and COMPANY_NAME = 'GOO' group by state order by state
union 
select
    state,
    count(*)as "FB_Records", to_char(SUM(average_sal),'$999,999') as "FB_AVGSAL"
    from company_details 
where company_status = 'OPEN' and COMPANY_NAME = 'FB' group by state order by state
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: I tried using pivot but my DB is still in 10g and I m trying with self join. I got stuck with forming my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  state,
  GooCount,
  GooCount   / Total AS AVG_GOO,
  sCOPECount,
  SCOPECount / Total AS AVG_SCOPE,
  FBCOunt, 
  FBCount    / Total AS AVG_FB,
  PALCount,
  PALCount   / Total AS AVG_PAL
FROM
(
    select
      state,
      SUM(CASE WHEN COMPANY_NAME = 'GOO'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GooCount, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN COMPANY_NAME = 'SCOPE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SCOPECount, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN COMPANY_NAME = 'FB'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FBCount, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN COMPANY_NAME = 'PAL'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PALCount,    
      COUNT(*) AS total
    from company_details 
    where company_status = 'OPEN'
    group by state order by state
) AS sub;
```